# Static analysis

Tags: binary-analysis, c

I am working on a class project. I need to find out static features of a program (without executing it).

1. Backward branches (loops)
2. Conditional branches (potential threads with load imbalance)
3. Interrupts (indicates synchronization, or IO, ...)

How can I find this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Do you want to find this information statically or do you want to detect these conditions when you are executing inside a debugger-like program?